# URDF and joint_state_publisher

Tags: urdf, joint-state-publisher, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to create a new robot model that implements a LIDAR and a camera, all of that using rtabmap_ros.

In order to do that, I created the following basic URDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="erl_ugv">
  <link name="base_footprint"/>
  <link name="base_link"/>
  <link name="laser_link"/>

  <joint name="base_link_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_footprint"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0.025" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>

  <joint name="laser_link_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="laser_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.08 0.006 0.44" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

(it's the fixed structure of the robot). I also created the parser.cpp file as explained on this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Parse%20a%20urdf%20file)

I tried to make all of this work thanks to the following launch file:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="model"/>
  <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find erl_ugv_description)/urdf/erl_ugv.urdf"/>
  <param name="use_gui" value="true"/>
  <param name="use_sim_time" value="false"/>

  <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" respawn="false"/>
  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"/>

  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find erl_ugv_description)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_laser_link" args="0.08 0.006 0.44 0 0 0 /base_link /base_laser_link 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser" args="0.08 0.006 0.44 0 0 0 /base_link /laser 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="camera_link" args="0.095 0 0.225 0 0 0 /base_link /camera_link 100" />
</launch>
```

with erl_ugv_description being the name of the dedicated package created in my **catkin_ws**

The thing is, when I roslaunch the previous file, I get the expected **tf** and **axes** in rviz. But also an error that says

```
[joint_state_publisher-2] process has died
```

I'm wondering whether the non completion of [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Using%20urdf%20with%20robot_state_publisher) on creating a state_publisher node with a C++ code is responsible for my failure. I'm asking this here because I don't understand how I could adapt the C++ code to my situation (a fixed structure, so what about the **odom_trans**, **hinc**, etc ? ...).

Thanks !

## EDIT

Here is the log of the **roslaunch** with the launch file pasted at the beginning of this post.

```
 turtlebot@turtlebot-14:~/erl/logs_new$ roslaunch erl_ugv_description beta.launch... logging to /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/072eb570-7041-11e7-93b9-605718b05f9f/roslaunch-turtlebot-14-4597.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://10.42.0.148:33667/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: indigo
 * /rosversion: 1.11.21
 * /use_gui: True
 * /use_sim_time: False

NODES
  /
    base_laser_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    camera_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    laser (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.42.0.148:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[joint_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [4615]
process[robot_state_publisher-2]: started with pid [4616]
process[rviz-3]: started with pid [4619]
process[base_laser_link-4]: started with pid [4620]
process[laser-5]: started with pid [4621]
process[camera_link-6]: started with pid [4626]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 347, in <module>
    jsp = JointStatePublisher()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 108, in __init__
    self.gui = JointStatePublisherGui("Joint State Publisher", self)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher", line 287, in __init__
    panel.SetScrollRate(0,slider.GetSize().GetHeight()+row.GetSize().GetHeight())
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slider' referenced before assignment
[joint_state_publisher-1] process has died [pid 4615, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher __name:=joint_state_publisher __log:=/home/turtlebot/.ros/log/072eb570-7041-11e7-93b9-605718b05f9f/joint_state_publisher-1.log].
log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/072eb570-7041-11e7-93b9-605718b05f9f/joint_state_publisher-1*.log
```

I then choose to kill RVIZ, which me and my colleague thought could handle what the C++ code would be supposed to do (but it doesn't).

```
================================================================================REQUIRED process [rviz-3] has died!
    process has finished cleanly
    log file: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/072eb570-7041-11e7-93b9-605718b05f9f/rviz-3*.log
    Initiating shutdown!
    ================================================================================
```

Furthermore, when I read this C++ code, it talks about odometry and movement, but my structure (urdf) is fixed !

## EDIT 2

As said in this [old post](http://answers.ros.org/question/43157/trying-to-use-get-joint-state-with-my-urdf/),

> It reads the position of the encoders
> in all joints and constructs a
> sensor_msgs/JointState message that is
> then published on the /joint_states
> topic.
>
> If you are running on a real robot,
> you need to implement such a node.

So, I have to write a node that publishes **sensors_msgs/JointState**, but what to I put inside my node if my urdf is only about **fixed joints** ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267059/urdf-and-joint_state_publisher/) by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-21**:
It's not really possible to figure out why the node died without seeing your code. I know that you followed the tutorial, but there could be errors in your code. Also, is that all that ROS is telling you?

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-24**:
that's the thing, I didn't follow the last tutorial with the C++ code (thus, nothing is compiled/executed), because I don't understand the use of this code & a colleague seems to make all of this work without the C++ script.

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-24**:
see my **Edit** in the question for what ROS is telling me when I roslaunch my custom .launch. See **EDIT 2** for question clarification.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-24**:
Did you look into the part of the traceback that says `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slider' referenced before assignment`?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-24**:
Also, what were you and your colleague expecting `RViz` to do? It visualizes topics and information.

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-24**:
Solve (magically ? ... :P) the joint_state_publisher error ... `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'slider' referenced before assignment` isn't coming from my code. Could it be a ROS code bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the referenced post is in regards to moving joints as encoders for the joints are mentioned. As far as I know if you don't care about publishing moving joints then you should be able to publish the transforms using the `urdf` file. You will need to give the transformation between `base_footprint` and `odom` frames, however.

You'll need a way to publish odometry. Take a look at this [navigation tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom#Using_tf_to_Publish_an_Odometry_transform) that goes over how to publish the odometry (as an example and for learning purposes). Of course, you can also use a localization package such as `rtabmap_ros`, as you mentioned in your question. Check out the [`rtabmap_ros` tutorial on navigation and mapping](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/MappingAndNavigationOnTurtlebot) for help with that.

**Edit**

I would say that the `joint_state_publisher` is unnecessary (and is definitely crashing as you've said). Try running your launch file with out that node running as it isn't necessary. From the [`joint_state_publisher` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher#Overview), the `joint_state_publisher`

> finds all of the non-fixed joints and publishes a JointState message with all those joints defined.

so you shouldn't need it because you only have fixed joints.

For the transforms, you want `map` -> `odom` -> `base_link` -> `other_frames` (not `base_link` -> `odom`). From the [`hector_mapping` wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping#Provided_tf_Transforms), it provides the `map` -> `odom` transformations. Now, you just need `odom` -> `base_link`.

Yes, `rtabmap_ros` *can provide this transformation*! Just look at the section titled 4.3.6 Provided Transforms under the [Visual Odometry section](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Visual_Odometry) and you'll see that it does indeed provide that transform.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-24**:
the publishing of the transforms **does work** & they appear in rivz, the aim of my question is to know whether the error logs quoted originate from the lack of a state_publisher node, and how to write such a node if needed. How do I link base_footprint and odom frames, if no odometry is published ?

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-24**:
it doesn't make sense to publish odometry out of nowhere: I want this urdf to describe the robot with which I'm going to use **hector_mapping** and **rtabmap_ros**, where *hector_mapping will publish odometry* thanks to a UTM-30LX lidar, and **rtabmap_ros** will build an occupancy_grid

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-24**:
Updated the answer to (hopefully) clarify things.

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-25**:
You link the turtlebot rtabmap tutorial,which doesn't apply-creating my own robot with dedicated URDF (hence my problems !). I'm using the Kinect + 2D laser [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot). Indeed, neither hector_mapping nor rtabmap provide TF(base_... -> odom)

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-25**:
Which leads me to 2 questions: 1) is this joint_state_publisher really a problem 2) how to solve it if it's the case ( 3) find that missing TF, but different matter I guess)

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-25**:
Yes ! But the frustrating thing is that robot_state_publisher apparently still **needs** joint_state_publisher to work & it is responsible for the publication of the fixed joints as well (see [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher#Subscribed_topics))

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-25**:
It doesn't *need* it. I was using it today without the the joint publisher and it worked. From the link in the answer, it says that it *can* be used with the state publisher.

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-07-25**:
ok, I wasn't sure of it, but I guess that's possible since I still get the tf defined by the fixed joints in rviz anyway. Thanks ! About rtabmap_ros, I'll look into it, ans ask elsewhere if needed since it's a different matter.